# Routing error in R

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Ruby and Ruby on rails and have hit a problem with routing.  I have 3 controllers, application controller, a bike controller and a ride controller.  My routing table is as follows:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'cycle_tracker/index'

  resources :rides
  resources :bikes

  root 'cycle_tracker#index'
```

When I run `rails routes` it brings the following:

```
  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
cycle_tracker_index GET    /cycle_tracker/index(.:format) cycle_tracker#index
              rides GET    /rides(.:format)               rides#index
                    POST   /rides(.:format)               rides#create
           new_ride GET    /rides/new(.:format)           rides#new
          edit_ride GET    /rides/:id/edit(.:format)      rides#edit
               ride GET    /rides/:id(.:format)           rides#show
                    PATCH  /rides/:id(.:format)           rides#update
                    PUT    /rides/:id(.:format)           rides#update
                    DELETE /rides/:id(.:format)           rides#destroy
              bikes GET    /bikes(.:format)               bikes#index
                    POST   /bikes(.:format)               bikes#create
           new_bike GET    /bikes/new(.:format)           bikes#new
          edit_bike GET    /bikes/:id/edit(.:format)      bikes#edit
               bike GET    /bikes/:id(.:format)           bikes#show
                    PATCH  /bikes/:id(.:format)           bikes#update
                    PUT    /bikes/:id(.:format)           bikes#update
                    DELETE /bikes/:id(.:format)           bikes#destroy
               root GET    /                              cycle_tracker#index
```

In my main view I have the following (I'm simply trying to create a link from my main page to rides/new.

```
<%= link_to 'rides', :controller => new_ride_path %>
```

If I try and access http://127.0.0.1:3000/rides/new then it works as expected.  However, if I simply try and access http://127.0.0.1:3000 then I get the following:

```
showing D:/Dev/CycleTracker/app/views/cycle_tracker/index.html.erb where line #2 raised:

No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"rides/new"}
```

If I try to use new_ride_url instead of path I get the following:

```
 Showing D:/Dev/CycleTracker/app/views/cycle_tracker/index.html.erb where line #2 raised:

No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"http://127.0.0.1:3000/rides/new"}
```

I imagine this is probably a fairly straightforward issue, but any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<%= link_to 'rides', new_ride_path %>`

Try that - you don't need the `:controller =>` part

Comment: It was that simple!  All the examples I've seen said to use the controller bit, but never mind.  Thanks for that.

Comment: It may be an old syntax from a previous version of Rails? Not sure as I have never seen it used that way. In general just the `_path` name is what is needed.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use the controller-action style you need to do this:

```
<%= link_to "Rides" , controller: "rides", action: "new" %>
```